# audio interface to add additional outputs to computer for Skype and teamspeak

Tags: computer, audio-interfaces

I want to use multiple applications such as teamspeak and Skype that allow me to select separate audio inputs/outputs from the system out. Note that I am on a mac.

I would like to take said audio inputs/outputs and send them to an external mixer, where I could then use the audio normally. preferably not converting to analog and back in the process.

My question is not a product recommendation, but rather a question about how audio interfaces appear to a computer.

I would like to be able to select pairs of channels on a multichannel interface and use them for each application. for example: pair 1/2 would be used for the inputs and outputs to Skype and pair 3/4 would be used for the inputs and outputs to teamspeak.

a final hope would be that I could use Dante connections for this, but it is a hope at best.

Note: I would be using this on gaming livestreams so i can separate my game audio from my friends on teamspeak and my own mic.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you are over-complicating things.  Teamspeak already offers pretty strong routing capabilities to pick where it does and doesn't get sound from.  If your stream application has a similar level of selectivity, you should be able to route around it and maybe at most combine to audio outputs (one from the game and one from your comms) into your headset with a basic mixer.

Comment: I want the tactile feedback of an external mixer. Also the system needs to interface with some outboard gear and i already have the mixer (digital is the way to go).

Comment: you can still get the tactile by binding a control surface to the inputs, but since you already have the mixer, I guess that is irrelevant.  What kind of mixer do you have?  That will determine the options for digitally feeding it in and out.

Comment: I have a Yamaha LS916, but I can buy a card for my mixer that supports any of the standard digital audio formats such as ADAT, Dante, MADI, AES etc. I would prefer to be able to do 8x8 over one cable.

Comment: I asked this question on this sub site because it appeared to be the closest in topic to my question. If there is a better place for it, feel free to migrate the question, otherwise please open it again, as I feel that the users of this sub-site would have the requisite knowledge and interest in this question.

Comment: This probably is the closest SE for what you are trying to do.  SuperUser might also be able to help since you are still effectively talking about signal routing in Mac audio, which is more of a computer thing.  The only part that bridges over in to Sound Design is the ASIO and sound board components, but it sounds like that part may be limited to just the ability to map your ASIO interface internally to Mac audio devices.  (Note, I didn't vote to close your question, but I also don't feel strongly enough to reopen it either.)

Answer (score 1):

Is an audio interface a requirement?  It seems to me you could internally route these signals with a software solution.  I am not a mac user, but on the windows platform there is a piece of software called `Virtual Audio Cable` that allows you to create additional audio channels and patch them how you see fit.  I suspect a similar solution exists for Macs.

I've utilized it in the past for streaming purposes when I needed to mix two sources into my microphone input and remove my microphone output from my own monitoring/playback.  It is quite robust and allows you to pipe multiple audio sources to a channel that can then be utilized by your broadcast as a single audio stream.

Comment: yes it is in this specific application. I would like to use an external mixer and be able to connect to some of my external gear. Also I was hoping for more general info about audio interfaces/dante, and how they appear to the selected programs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do complex routing with a Mac it is quite simple. Open Audio MIDI settings and create an aggregate device, this will allow you to connect multiple audio interfaces and route audio between applications.

http://lifehacker.com/5933282/how-to-aggregate-and-use-multiple-audio-inputs-and-outputs-in-os-x

I would recommend installing Soundflower as well: http://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/

Comment: please read the question. I asked about an external audio interface. I already know about the aggregate devices and soundflower/wavtap/jack for audio routing. I am asking about how external audio interfaces show up in the audio preferences, and can i separate out pairs of channels to route separately to specific applications